# Hamburger menu lines are not same height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a hamburger menu, however, the height of the individual menu lines is inconsistent. The middle line looks to be the actual height while the top and bottom appear smaller.

If I zoom in you can see:
[image: Zoomed version of inconsistent hamburger menu lines].

A zoomed-out version looks like this:

[image: Regular view of inconsistent hamburger menu lines].

```css
.burger span {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
}

.burger span:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.burger span:last-of-type {
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="burger">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

If I increase the height of the menu lines to 3px then the top and bottom lines will look larger. If I increase the height to 4px then they will maintain a consistent height. Any help as to why this may be.

Comment: im guessing the margin is making the height of the first child and the last child to be smaller.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of browser subpixel calculation! It looks correct in FF, Chrome and Safari on os 12.4. One thing you could try is using  `top` values rather than margin, but you may get the same result. What browser are you using?

Comment: Interesting, I am using the latest version of Chrome, just restarted and everything.

Comment: @disinfor is actually right, it works in my code, may I ask what browser are you using?

Comment: If you are using Windows, do you have your display on your system set to a zoom level?

Comment: I am using a new laptop and the display settings were set to 125%. Thank you for that catch @disinfor! Now that I have adjusted everything is looking good.

Comment: Awesome! I'm going to add my comment as an answer as I think people run into this issue more often than we think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for future visitors (non-code related):

1. If using a Windows machine, check the system display zoom settings. This is most likely the culprit - (this was the issue for this question)
2. Check your browser zoom settings.

Code related:

1. Use different measurement values - `px`, `rem` or `em` to test. May be a subpixel render issue.